# Excel Index Match Returning Value instead of Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am using Index Match in my sheet. The problem is the Index() is returning the value of the cell not the formula within the cell. Is there a way to return the actual formula an not the value?

My IndexMatch formula looks like this:

```
=Index(ProductTypeRef!$A$2:$B$11, Match(L2, ProductTypeRef!$A$2:$A$11, 0), 2)
```

The cells that are being referenced look like this:

```
="Folder for 5in by 7in paper. With "&INDIRECT("SanrioShop!M"&Match(A3,SanrioShop!$L$1:$L$71, 0))&" as the theme"
```

I want to return the actual formula, not the string that is created by the formula.

If the formula referncee returns M2 then M2 is returned in the IndexMatch Table.  But I want the IndexMatch Table to return the current row, not M2.

Comment: you can't do that with a formula.  Formula return values and not the underlying thing.

Comment: Okay I figured values were the onty thing that could be returned, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FORMULATEXT` function - it returns underlying formula for given reference.

In your case:

```
=FORMULATEXT(Index(ProductTypeRef!$A$2:$B$11,Match(L2,ProductTypeRef!$A$2:$A$11,0),2))
```

[image]